# Flow 'When an item is deleted' never triggers, item just gets deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, microsoft-flow

I have a Flow which has the following trigger:

[image]

[image]

However, when I delete an Item from the associated list, the trigger doesn't work as the list item gets deleted.

I can confirm this by placing a 'Get item' right after the trigger, and I get the following error:

```
Error
Action 'Get_item' failed

Error Details
Item Not Found
clientRequestId: 24bd6483-4d58-434b-99da-c74b7da0c27b
serviceRequestId: 24bd6483-4d58-434b-99da-c74b7da0c27b
```

This makes sense, as the list item has been deleted in SharePoint, so the trigger can't 'Get' the item.

What I don't get is:

**Shouldn't the item wait until the workflow is 'approved' before being deleted?**

How do I make the list 'wait' until the approval is finished before actually deleting the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow triggers always run once event is already occurred it will not wait til item is approved or anything. If you triggering point is item deleted, it does trigger MS flow(just tried this) but it won't anything for status as you trigger is when item is deleted. If you want to handle situation than item is deleted when it is only approved. you should change flow logic

Change flow triggering point to when item is edited.

Put a if condition to check if item is approved, if item is approved then only delete a item.

Answer (score 1):

As per the last answer: Workflows always run "after" the event.

You could, however, use [remote event receivers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint). If you use [SPRemoteEventType.ItemDeleting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.remoteapp.spremoteeventtype?view=sharepoint-server) you will get notified before the event is processed (i.e. before the item is really "gone"). You could create a flow with a http-request-trigger (it's "premium", though) to process the event.